# How Do I Delete Misnamed Tagged Directory Already Committed?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm new to using the SVN system and having hard time figuring out how to delete files uploaded mistakenly.

What I've done:

1. Committed the trunk folder with right clicking on "SVN Commit"
2. Right clicked and choose "TortoiseSVN" -> "Branch/Tag"
3. In the section of "To path:" in the "Branch/Tag - Tortoise" window, I typed `/*mydirectory*/tags/*1.0.11*` where 1.0.11 was supposed to be 1.0.1.1
4. After realizing 1.0.11 was a mistake, to remove the directory, I right clicked on the 1.0.11 folder in Windows and selected "TortoiseSVN" -> "Delete"

It deleted the folder in Windows but does not delete the folder in the remote server.

According to this page,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092344/how-do-i-delete-a-wrongly-tagged-directory-in-svn, a command can be used and I tried to type `svn` in the command prompt window but it gives `svn is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

This should be a very basic question but I could not find relevant pages. Some pages suggest to use `revert` but I've already committed 1.0.1.1 so I'm afraid doing revert causes the newest one to be deleted.

Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 choices

- If your TSVN is 1.7.*, you can have svn-cli client installed with TortoiseSVN in TortoiseSVN's bin dir (if it was enabled at install-stage)

c:\Program Files_Tools\TortoiseSVN\bin>dir *.exe /B
`...
svn.exe
svnadmin.exe
svndumpfilter.exe
svnlook.exe
svnrdump.exe
svnserve.exe
svnsync.exe
svnversion.exe
...`

thus: if you don't have these files: reinstall TSVN with all needed components, if you have files: add dir to PATH or use full-path in comand-line

- With only TSVN you can use Repo Browser and commands in RB's context-menu (namely: "Rename" with wrongly-named tag selected in repository tree)

Comment: Wao, `repo-browser` just did it. Thanks. But it's really slow. As for the components, I'm using v1.7 and could not find those files so I may need to re-install the program later on. By the way, if I make this kind of mistake again in the future, what should I do first? Is it fine just using repo-browser or should I use the command line tool or is `revert` supposed to be for this kind of operation?

Comment: @Teno - I'll prefer to use pure CLI-solution `svn mv OLD-URL NEW-URL`, because: not revert, but back-merge will produce one additional commit, RepoBrowser give us *some overhead* of GUI